# Npm install error Typings : command not found

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

So i'm trying to fix my npm because of permission errors. So I reinstalled it. Now when I get to the 'typings' part it says typings: command not found. I think it has something to do with Angular and TypeScript? Can anyone help? I used `sudo npm install`

```
...
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_context.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_functions.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_util.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_values.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/source_map.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/subset_map.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_c.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_value.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/units.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/utf8_string.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/util.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/values.o
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o ../src/binding.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o ../src/create_string.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/custom_function_bridge.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/custom_function_bridge.o ../src/custom_function_bridge.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/custom_importer_bridge.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/custom_importer_bridge.o ../src/custom_importer_bridge.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_context_wrapper.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_context_wrapper.o ../src/sass_context_wrapper.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/boolean.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/boolean.o ../src/sass_types/boolean.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/color.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/color.o ../src/sass_types/color.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/error.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/error.o ../src/sass_types/error.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/factory.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/factory.o ../src/sass_types/factory.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/list.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/list.o ../src/sass_types/list.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/map.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/map.o ../src/sass_types/map.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/null.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/null.o ../src/sass_types/null.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/number.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/number.o ../src/sass_types/number.cpp
      c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/include/node -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/src -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/sann/.node-gyp/8.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/string.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/string.o ../src/sass_types/string.cpp
      c++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-no_pie -Wl,-search_paths_first -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -L./Release -stdlib=libc++  -o Release/binding.node Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/custom_function_bridge.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/custom_importer_bridge.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_context_wrapper.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/boolean.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/color.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/error.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/factory.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/list.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/map.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/null.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/number.o Release/obj.target/binding/src/sass_types/string.o Release/sass.a 
    gyp info ok 
    Installed to /Users/sann/GIT/buddy-NEC/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57/binding.node

    > angular2-truncate@0.1.3 postinstall /Users/sann/GIT/buddy-NEC/node_modules/angular2-truncate
    > typings install

    sh: typings: command not found
    npm ERR! file sh
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno ENOENT
    npm ERR! syscall spawn
    npm ERR! angular2-truncate@0.1.3 postinstall: `typings install`
    npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-truncate@0.1.3 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/sann/.npm/_logs/2017-10-05T12_59_45_212Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was fixed by reinstalling npm.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo npm install`. You most likely need escalated privileges.